# Two table views in view controller: Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` with prototype cells that essentially takes up the whole page. I have a `UIButton` on the very bottom that should display a pop-up static `UITableView` when tapped. I'm struggling to account for the pop-up table view in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let result: UITableViewCell

        if tableView == self.tableView {

            var cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell

            cell.textLabel!.text = array[indexPath.row]

            result = cell

        } else if tableView == self.popUpTableView {

            var popUpCell = self.popUpTableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("popUpCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell

            popUpCell.textLabel!.text = popUpArray[indexPath.row]

            result = popUpCell

        }

        return result
    }
```

I'm getting an error at `return result`, where `Variable 'result' used before being initialized`, but I'm declaring it at the very top. Where am I going wrong with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have exhaustive choices.  It's possible that result never gets initialized because your checks are "if" and "else if".  What happens if tableView is not either "self.tableView" or "self.popUpTableView"?

The simple fix is (if you only plan on having these two) to simply change your "else if" to a simple "else".  This way result will always get initialized.